# Having problems with python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, list

i have some ...

```
[{"countryname": "Republic of Tunisia", "project_name": "TN: DTF Social Protection Reforms Support", "lendprojectcost": 5700000}, 
{"countryname": "Republic of Tunisia", "project_name": "Tunisia: Ecotourism and Conservation of Desert Biodiversity", "lendprojectcost": 9050000},
{"countryname": "Republic of Tunisia", "project_name": "Tunisia - Communications for policy reforms", "lendprojectcost": 600000},
{"countryname": "Republic of Tunisia", "project_name": "Tunisia - Governance, Opportunities and Jobs DPL", "lendprojectcost": 500000000}]
```

I want:

```
[{"countryname": "Republic of Tunisia", "project_name":all projects, "lendprojectcost":sum(..) }]
```

how i can do this?
I used Python/Flask/MongoDB.

Comment: Please make your code python-looking, with variables names. We are all old, nearsighted, glass-wearing guys, and parsing raw JSON really hurts.

Comment: use some `for` loop to do it.

Comment: How do you want your `all_projects`: as a list, as a string, etc?

Comment: @engineercoding That's just the sum of costs. The OP wants a sum of costs and a list of projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may firstly create a `dict` object via using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for making the unique entry of each `"countryname"`. Then transform the `dict` to your desired response.

For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

country_project, country_sum = defaultdict(list), defaultdict(int)

for country in country_list:
    country_name = country["countryname"]
    country_project[country_name].append(country['project_name'])
    country_sum[country_name] += country['lendprojectcost']

# Map the `dict` to get desired result using list comprehension
new_list = [ {
        'countryname': country,
        'project_name': country_project[country],
        'lendprojectcost': country_sum[country]} for country in country_project]

# OR, via using plain `for` loop as:
# new_list = []
# for country in country_project:
#     new_list.append({
#         'countryname': country,
#         'project_name': country_project[country],
#         'lendprojectcost': country_sum[country]})
```

where `country_list` is the original list mentioned in the question and the final value hold by `my_list` is the desired result:

```
[{
    'countryname': 'Republic of Tunisia', 
    'project_name': [
        'TN: DTF Social Protection Reforms Support', 
        'Tunisia: Ecotourism and Conservation of Desert Biodiversity', 
        'Tunisia - Communications for policy reforms', 
        'Tunisia - Governance, Opportunities and Jobs DPL'
    ], 
    'lendprojectcost': 515350000
}]
```

Comment: Howabout `new_list = [{'countryname': country, 'project_name': country_project[country],
        'lendprojectcost': country_sum[country]} for country in country_project]`. List comprehensions rulez.

Comment: @DYZ: I thought it might be too complex for user. But after seeing your comment and giving it the second thought, I think I should have mentioned that as well. Updated the answer

Comment: Wait, what's `country_list`?

Comment: It is mentioned in the answer *"where country_list is the original list mentioned in the question"*

Comment: @R.B Also check the 5-line pandas-based answer that I posted. It does not require the knowledge of the country list.

Answer (score 0):

Being a pandas geek, I would go for a pandas solution: create a data frame from the original data (let's call it `raw`), do all necessary aggregations, and construct another dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(raw)
result_df = df.groupby('countryname').agg({
                       'lendprojectcost' : np.sum,
                       'project_name'    : lambda col: col.tolist()})
result = result_df.reset_index().to_dict(orient="records")

# [{"countryname":"Republic of Tunisia","project_name":["TN: DTF Social Protection Reforms Support","Tunisia: Ecotourism and Conservation of Desert Biodiversity","Tunisia - Communications for policy reforms","Tunisia - Governance, Opportunities and Jobs DPL"],"lendprojectcost":515350000}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are great, but this seems like a natural problem for `reduce`. You have a list, and you're trying to combine the elements in the list with operations in order to "reduce" the list size down to one element:

```
def update(x, y):
    x["project_name"].append(y["project_name"])
    x["lendprojectcost"] += y["lendprojectcost"]
    return x

result = [reduce(update, list_of_dicts, {"countryname": "Republic of Tunisia",
                                         "project_name": [],
                                         "lendprojectcost": 0})]
```

Bonus feature: No imports required